# How can I check which JRE version I have?

Tags: neo4j

I tried `java -version`, but it returned something like:

```
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

According to the program I am trying to start, it requires `Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7 or 8`.

Comment: The number after the 1. In this case, you're on JRE 7. If it really needs the Oracle JRE, see http://askubuntu.com/q/56104/158442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Oracle Java which you can install like this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and then setup like this

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Right now you have OpenJDK and as per your question you need Oracle Java.
In case the JAVA_HOME is not setup properly you can do:

```
sudo vi /etc/environment
export JAVA_HOME=/path-to-java-before-bin-dir
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: Should I remove the old java? I don't want it to interfere with the new one, and the system is low on memory. Will it have any effect on the Ubuntu if I remove it?

Comment: @inf3rno. No you don't have to. The steps that i have provided doesn't purge openJDK. It's just make sure that you get Oracle Java 8 from the right PPA(so that you get future updates and bug fixes) and then it will make sure that it's Oracle Java 8 is invoked when you issue java(provided you setup path properly). If this solves your problem - mark this as answer(tick mark)

Comment: Thanks! I'll purge it, I guess programs which used that version are compatible with the oracle version.